# HTML table multiple forms Ajax submit

Tags: html, ajax

I have a table with multiple rows and multiple forms and I am trying to send each form to my PHP script.

When not using Ajax all the forms update correctly. However with Ajax I cannot get the PHP script to work. How can I get the Ajax to work?

On HTML part, I have multiple rows which belong to one form (In the example below all the rows belong to one form and I have multiple of these). I did read that a FORM tag cannot be under TR tag and even know when I look at the code it looks pretty ugly, but I am not sure how else I can build the table.

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'post.php', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $(this).serialize(), // post data || get data
            })
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <form id="form1" method="POST" action=""></form>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="">
    <td rowspan="6">bls</td>
    <td rowspan="6">qasachin.dwxmp41@mailinator.com</td>
    <td>Records</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Records"></td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Contact"></td>
    <td rowspan="6"><textarea id="usrform" name="comment">Tadas</textarea></td>
    <td><button type="submit" id="submit" value="approve" class="btn btn-warning">Approve</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Centers</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Centers"></td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Tadas</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Company"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Duration</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Duration"></td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Address"></td>
    <td><button type="submit" formaction="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Invoice</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>GCP</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="GCP"></td>
    <td>Zip</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Zip"></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="mailto:qasachin.dwxmp41@mailinator.com" class="btn btn-success>Email</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>RAND</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="RAND"></td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>Amsterdam</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="City"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>€39</td>
    <td>€18</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Price"></td>
    <td>Departm</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Departm"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML markup.

Only `td` and `th` elements are allowed to be child elements of [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

And you are immediately closing your `form` tag. Which means you don't have any fields inside your form.

You should put your whole `table` inside your `form`.

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="6">bls</td>
                <td rowspan="6">qasachin.dwxmp41@mailinator.com</td>
                <td>Records</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Records"></td>
                <td>Contact</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Contact"></td>
                <td rowspan="6"><textarea id="usrform" name="comment">Tadas</textarea></td>
                <td><button type="submit" id="submit" value="approve" class="btn btn-warning">Approve</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centers</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Centers"></td>
                <td>Company</td>
                <td>Tadas</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Company"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Duration</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Duration"></td>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Address"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" formaction="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Invoice</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GCP</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="GCP"></td>
                <td>Zip</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Zip"></td>
                <td><a target="_blank" href="mailto:qasachin.dwxmp41@mailinator.com" class="btn btn-success>Email</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RAND</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="RAND"></td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Amsterdam</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="City"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>€39</td>
                <td>€18</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Price"></td>
                <td>Departm</td>
                <td>IT</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="1" value="" name="Departm"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

You also need to handle the `submit` event on your form or your page will be reloaded.
You can do that by calling `e.preventDefault()` inside the handler.

```
$(function(){
    // click on button submit
    $("#form1").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload on submit
        // send ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'post.php', // url where to submit the request
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : $(this).serialize(), // post data || get data
        })
    });
});
```